# Can the powershell pipeline monad be broken without an assignment?

Tags: powershell

In all the examples I've come across, the pipeline monad is only broken when an assignment is made. That is:

```
$result = ls | %{$_.FullName} | select -first
```

Without the assignment, the output of the above statement is a pipeline of exactly one item (due to the use of `select -first`), that defaults to writing to `write-host`.

Is it possible to break the pipeline monad so that the result is a single value *without* assigning it to a variable or equivalent (eg. passing the result as an argument to a Cmdlet that accepts a string)

(The LINQ equivalent to what I'm after is `First()`, which breaks the `IEnumerable` monad by returning the first actual value)

NOTE: I have no practical use for an answer to this question, it's simply academic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** Roman is right, not sure how it worked for me to begin with. Updated.

It appears that the simplest way is to simply access the first item:

```
( @{Value = 1}, @{Value = 2} )[0].Value
```

Which will face gracefully if there are no items:

```
@()[0].Value
```

Comment: Hmm, my results are different. In V2 I see nothing. In V3 I see 2 items: 1, 2.